# How to control the buffer size for numpy array elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, size, buffer

The idea here is to dynamically increase the size (rows X columns) of an array (using hstack and vstack). However, I do not know the length of the strings that are about to be written at a specific position of the array at the moment I have to increase the size. Thus, the unknown elements are initialized with e.g. ' ' or 0 or something similar.

This leads to an error, if the placeholders are too short:

```
x = array([["1;", "2;"],["3;", "4;"]])
x[0][0] = "1234567890;"
print x
```

delivers:

```
[['12' '2;']
 ['3;' '4;']]
```

Many characters are missing at the position [0][0],
 whereas

```
x = array([["1;", "2;"],["abcdefghij;", "4;"]])
x[0][0] = "1234567890;"
print x
```

delivers the desired result, i.e.:

```
[['1234567890;' '2;']
 ['abcdefghij;' '4;']]
```

How can we handle this in Python? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use a numpy array and not a list (or list of lists)?

Comment: I did not think about using nested lists because I did not expect any difficulties here. Would you recommend the nested lists way? If yes, why? Thanks!

Comment: And also why you usa an numpy as if it were a list?

Comment: That is probably due to my lacking programming skill. The main reasons for choosing numpy arrays are the vstack and hstack methods. You could do it without them, though.

Comment: Its the thingy I myself often miss, but telling, what you finally want to achieve (the basic problem behind it) will let you receive help in the most precise way

Comment: What I am trying to do is parsing binary data that then has to be sorted in an array (or a 2 dimensional list, if you want). The position at which each element should be is also coded in the binary data. At the beginning, I do not know how many elements there will be and what they will look like, so I thought hstack and vstack are convenient methods. Would you suggest using nested lists is the way to go here? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays is not that good for dealing with non numerical types i believe, but if you still want to use it this is what you can do.

You can manually set the dtype of the array to either `object` or `'S#'` where # will be the maximum number of characters.

```
In [19]: x = np.array([["1;", "2;"],["3;", "4;"]], dtype=object)

In [20]: x
Out[20]:
array([['1;', '2;'],
       ['3;', '4;']], dtype=object)

In [21]: x[0,0] = "1234567890;"

In [22]: x
Out[22]:
array([['1234567890;', '2;'],
       ['3;', '4;']], dtype=object)


In [24]: x = np.array([["1;", "2;"],["3;", "4;"]], dtype='S64')

In [25]: x
Out[25]:
array([['1;', '2;'],
       ['3;', '4;']],
      dtype='|S64')

In [26]: x[0,0] = "1234567890;"

In [27]: x
Out[27]:
array([['1234567890;', '2;'],
       ['3;', '4;']],
      dtype='|S64')
```

Comment: That looks fine, thank you very much! I am going to try this tomorrow. However, as you also stated that numpy arrays are not the best choice for dealing with non-numerical types, would you recommend using nested lists or something else instead?